# Grid doesn't change even after reloading store while filtering

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I want a grid that will change or reload after delete any row and retrieve those rows that have same member id. For this, I add filter. Again I callback store with filter after delete any row. My store filter well but grid couldn't display it......It holds the previous display......

```
Ext.define('${pkgName}.v02x001001.SV02X00100101' , {
extend    : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias     : 'widget.sv02x00100101',
id        : 'sv02x00100101',
border    : true,
modal     : true,
height    : 300,
width     : 455,
viewConfig: {
    stripeRows    : true,
    forceFit      : true,
    emptyText     : 'No Records to display',
    listeners     : {
        viewready : function(v) {                    
            var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('S02X001001');               
            store = !store ? Ext.create("S02X001001") : store;
            var value = Ext.getCmp('member-sv02x00100104').getValue(),
            filters   = new Array();
            store.clearFilter();
            store.filter('member', value);
            filters.push({
                property : 'member', 
                value    : value
              });
            store.loadPage(1, {
                filters  : filters
             }); 
        }
    }
},
initComponent: function() {
    this.store  = 'S02X001001';     

    this.tbar= Ext.create('Ext.ux.StatusBar', {            
        topBorder       : false,
        statusAlign     : 'right',
        items    : [{
            xtype       :'button',
            text        : 'ADD',
            icon        : "${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'ADD01003.png')}",
            listeners   : {
                click   : this.onNewAddress
                }
        },'-']
    });

    this.columns = [
    {
        text            : 'Address Line 1',
        dataIndex       : 'addressline1', 
        sortable        : false,
        flex            : 1
    },{
        text            : 'Address Line 2',
        dataIndex       : 'addressline2',
        sortable        : false,
        width           : 170
    },{
        menuDisabled    : true,
        sortable        : false,
        id              : 'deletee',
        xtype           : 'actioncolumn',            
        width           : 22,            
        items           : [{
            icon        : "${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'DEL01005.png')}",
            tooltip     : 'Delete This?',
            scope       : this,
            handler     : function(grid, rowIdx, colIdx) {
                var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIdx);
                var conId  = record.data.id
                this.onDeleteClick(conId);
            }
        }]
    }]; 
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

onNewAddress: function(btn, e, eOpts){
    var view=Ext.widget('sv02x00100102');
    view.show();
    var a = Ext.getCmp('member-sv02x00100104').getValue();
            Ext.getCmp('member-sv02x00100102').setValue(a);
},
onDeleteClick:function(conId){
       Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title       : 'Delete',
        msg         : 'Really want to delete ?',
        icon        : Ext.Msg.WARNING,
        buttons     : Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
        buttonText  :{ 
            yes: "Delete", 
            no : "No" 
        },
        scope         : this,
        animateTarget : 'deletee',
        fn: function(btn, dbQty){
            if(btn == 'yes'){
                var registration = Ext.create('${appName}.model.M02X001001',{
                    id : conId
                });
                var store = this.getStore();
                registration.destroy({
                    scope   : this,
                    success : function(model, operation) { 
                        if(model != null){
                        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('S02X001001');               
                        store = !store ? Ext.create("S02X001001") : store;
                        var value = Ext.getCmp('member-sv02x00100104').getValue(),
                        filters   = new Array();
                        store.clearFilter();
                        store.filter('member', value);
                        filters.push({
                            property : 'member', 
                            value    : value
                          });
                        store.loadPage(1, {
                            filters  : filters
                        }); 
                       }
                    },
                    failure: function(){
                        console.log('Unable to delete');
                    }
                });           
            }                         
        }         
    });                    
 }
```

});

How it possible to retrieve rest of the relative rows ........

Here is my Store ..........

```
Ext.define('${pkgName}.S02X001001', {
extend    : 'Ext.data.Store',
model     : '${appName}.model.M02X001001',
idProperty: 'id',
autoLoad  : true,
autoSync  : true,
filterParam: 'query',
remoteSort: true,
proxy     : {
    type    : 'ajax',
    noCache : false,
    limitParam: 'limit',
    startParam: 'start',
    url : '${createLink(controller:'C02x001001', action: 'store')}',
    reader:{
        type            : 'json',
        root            : 'data',
        totalProperty   : 'total',
        successProperty : 'success',
        messageProperty : 'message',
        implicitIncludes: true
    },
    simpleSortMode  : true
},
sorters: [{
    property: 'id', 
    direction: 'asc'
}]
```

});

Comment: A grid bind itself to a store and will from that on react on all events. So it makes no sense when you are saying that the store has all records but the grid don't show them... Is the store instance you are talking about really the store bound to the grid? And are you really sure that the records are loaded into the store?

Comment: yes Sra, it happens. I've a grid panel which retrieve filtered data. but when I delete any data, grid couldn't change though I call grid's store again in the success of delete function. I found filtered data in the store (Firebug). what's my bug.....

Comment: The grid is just a sort of presentation layer here, the data is in the store. If the store changes the grid would change to due to his binding. If that not happens you should recheck the references of the stores you work with as well if the store(s) can red your response. Because of the binding a grid can't react if the store suspend his events.

Comment: Sra, at last I found a slight association problem as I'm using Grails+ExtJS . For this grid acts something mysterious. Now it ok.

Answer (score 1):

it should be refresh the grid view in automatic,
but you can refresh the view by manual way :

use method getView().refresh();
try:

```
Ext.getCmp('sv02x00100101').getView().refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I tried your answer..... It remains same.. Grid holds the previous records ...............

Comment: maybe you want to try log the store record first.
use: console.log(store_name);
And then observe the data of he record (store.data.items).
if the record is the true data that response by server, it mean the mistake is not from the store.

Comment: No Funckye, may be i'm clear my demand. well. i.e.  I've five data of a specific member in a table BUT the have many data of other members. So i retrieve specific member's data by filtering and i used them in the view ready of grid panel. so my grid holds on data of particular member. Now if i delete one data of that particular member, how many data remains ? It should be four, isn't it ? database shows it four. but grid shows it five. that means grid doesn't reload the new records( present condition of the database). If i refresh my application , it shows four. that means ???

Comment: you should add this 'Ext.getCmp('sv02x00100101').getView().refresh();' after record delete on onDeleteClick();